Quantum ESPRESSO 7.0: Why ph.x does not produce .dyn files?
I am trying to calculate the electron-phonon coupling for a given structure (BaO2). I have downloaded the cif file and produced the scf.in file, as shown below, I have used pw.x to run this and produce scf.out. From the output i know to expect 6 representations, so 6 .dyn files. I then prepared ph.in file, as shown below. After running ph.x, only two dyn files are written, and one of them is empty. Further processing is thus stopped. Can someone elaborate where I have gone wrong? I am new to QE, and this has been causing issues since a few days. I just cant get ph.x to produce the dyn files properly. Is my input wrong? or is it an issue inherent to QE 7.0?. I cannot use phonopy because i need the output of ph.x for epw.x. I wanted some expert opinion to solve this issue.
I am using the SSSP potentials.

ph.in:
&inputph
  
outdir = './outdir/'
  
prefix = 'bao'
  
tr2_ph = 1.0d-14
  
ldisp = .true.
  
amass(1) = 137.327   ! Atomic mass of Ba
  
amass(2) = 137.327
  
amass(3) = 15.9994   ! Atomic mass of O
  
amass(4) = 15.9994
  
amass(5) = 15.9994
  
amass(6) = 15.9994
  
nq1 = 3
  
nq2 = 3
  
nq3 = 3
  
fildyn = 'bao.dyn'
/

scf.in:
&CONTROL

  calculation = 'scf'

  outdir='./outdir/'

  prefix = 'bao'

  pseudo_dir = '/home/dftserver2/qe-7.0_Pseudopot'

  restart_mode='from_scratch'

  verbosity='high'
/

&SYSTEM

  ecutrho =   4.5000000000d+02

  ecutwfc =   5.0000000000d+01

  ibrav = 0

  nat = 6

  ntyp = 2

/

&ELECTRONS

  conv_thr = 1e-10

  electron_maxstep = 80

/

ATOMIC_SPECIES

Ba 137.327 Ba.pbe-spn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF

O 15.9994 O.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.0.1.UPF

ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal

Ba           0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.0000000000 

Ba           0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.5000000000 

O            0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.8916642300 

O            0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.6083357700 

O            0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.3916642300 

O            0.5000000000       0.5000000000       0.1083357700 

K_POINTS automatic

9 9 5 0 0 0

CELL_PARAMETERS angstrom

      3.8380148200       0.0000000000       0.0000000000

      0.0000000000       3.8380148200       0.0000000000

      0.0000000000       0.0000000000       6.8981992700



From your input files, everything is good. But you have to attach also phonon calculation output file. At lease you have to write last line of phonon calculation output file. From given informations, I think that problem is 'out of memory'. Phonon calculation requires more computational power and RAM. Can you please provide us how many cores and how much RAM did you use.

I see. In my run, i used 32Gb of memory on 8 cores.
I have another server allocated to me with 128Gb of memory and 48 total cores for my use, I will go with that then.
